# "Send by email" on modern page - not showing for some users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, communication-site

Original question: While this feature was previously available for our site users it now is missing. There is no gray ribbon or "send by email" button. SHouldn't all visitors be able to send or share Events and News?
I'm not sure if this is a permission issue or something else. And not sure why that would have changed other than I made it a hub site recently.

Clarification on my question:  “send by email” on modern pages was not showing for some users.

I thought it was a permissions issue but as clarified in the answer below, it was a browser issue. In my experience “Send by email” for a modern page shows on IE 11, chrome, and safari. Some of our users were not seeing “share by email”. Based on the answer below I assume this is because they were using IE 10 but I have not confirmed this is the version they were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the “send by email” in the modern page?

If so, which IE did you use to display the modern page?

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, if I open the modern page in the IE 10, it will not display the “send by email” button in the modern page. If I open the modern page in the IE 11, it will display the “send by email” button in the modern page.

I suggest you could use IE 11 for modern page in SharePoint online.

More reference:

[Internet Explorer compatibility mode is changing on SharePoint Online.](https://microsofttouch.fr/english/b/vince365/posts/internet-explorer-compatibility-mode-is-changing-on-sharepoint-online)

Comment: Yes “send by email” in the modern page. It was another user, so I'm not sure what version - but I'm guessing IE 10. It works on my IE 11. I ended up having her use Chrome. But that is good to know. Thanks so much.