# For some users on some sites, the "Send by email"-button does not appear

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have an issue where on some of our modern SPO pages, for some of our users the "Send by email"-button is missing. Let's take one of our users as an example: He has two users: one regular user and one admin user. Using Edge, Chrome, Opera and Firefox to verify things, he found that while being logged in as his admin user, the "Send via email"-button appears as normal on this particular page, while being logged in using his regular account the "Send by email"-button is missing.

So as of now, it appears that the visibility of the "Send by email"-button has something to do with permissions. In contrast, [this SO post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257988/send-by-email-on-modern-page-not-showing-for-some-users) describes the same type of issue, with the underlying issue being browser based, but as we've tested using four different browsers, our issue does not appear to be a browser issue.

Have anyone else had this same issue, and could suggest some steps to debug this issue? Maybe there's a setting somewhere that needs to be toggled or something.

Comment: Does the user's regular account have at least contribute permission on the site?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with all kinds of users in my SPO environment and cannot reproduce this issue.

Here is the test outcome:

As long as the "Send by email" button is visible to the tenant administrator, the button is visible to everyone who has access to the same page, including:

1. Users with *View Only* permission
2. Guest users
3. Internal users even with no Exchange Online license or synced from on-premises.

In addition, according to other posts related to the "Send by email" feature (such as [UserVoice post](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/32833063-please-provide-option-to-customize-email-templates) / [TechCommunity post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-communication-sites-quot-send-by-email-quot-settings/m-p/97552)) , this is a feature we have no control of for the time being.

So my conclusion is: this is not a permission or browser related issue, but a temporary issue which cannot be fixed by end users.